# Mysql rank, asc or desc

Tags: mysql, ranking, rank

I have a query below that uses a ranking method based on `points`. The problem is if I order by asc the ranking still shows 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Instead of 4, 3, 2, 1.( Or if wanted to get only one persons rank (where username=name1) the result comes back 1, instead of their actual rank based on `points`).  My code is below:

```
SELECT username, @n := @n + 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `avg`, `1st places` + `2nd places` + `3rd places` AS `points`
FROM (SELECT username,  
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
format(avg(rating),0) `avg`

FROM contest_entries 
GROUP BY username 

) q, (SELECT @n := 0) n 
ORDER BY `points` desc
```

So what I want, is to be able to rank by `points` still, but if I want to order by asc the ranking would go in reverse ...4, 3, 2, 1. Is this possible?

Edit* This is what the it looks like when I use the above code.

```
username    ranking   1st places    2nd places  3rd places  avg points
name3          1       10               5            0       1    15
name1          2       10               0            0       1    10
name2          3       0                0            0       6     0
```

however when order by points asc, this is the result:

```
username    ranking   1st places    2nd places  3rd places  avg points
name2          1       0                0            0       6    0
name1          2       10               0            0       1    10
name3          3       10               5            0       1    15
```

The points are in reverse, but the ranking stays the same.

Comment: Please provide test data and the output you expect.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `mysql` ASC should show the DESC have you slept well ??

Comment: The select query doesn't mention 'point', is it part of the table? You may need name some of the search field with 'as point'

Comment: For ranking its still 0+1, 1+1, 2+1, 3+1 .... Doesn't matter how you order... So maybe what is you want is nest this query inside another query and then order by ranking

Comment: I edited the original to give you a better idea.

Comment: Please use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create your table and put some sample data.

Comment: see below for the links

Comment: Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from
(SELECT username, @n := @n - 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `avg`, `1st places` + `2nd places` + `3rd places` AS `points`
FROM (SELECT username,  
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
format(avg(rating),0) `avg`

FROM contest_entries 
GROUP BY username 

) q, (SELECT @n := count(distinct username)+1 from contest_entries) n 
ORDER BY `points` asc) resultset
order by ranking asc;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3363f/35)

If you need to add conditions:

```
 select * from
(SELECT username, @n := @n - 1 ranking, `1st places`, `2nd places`, `3rd places`, `avg`, `1st places` + `2nd places` + `3rd places` AS `points`
FROM (SELECT username,  
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 1 THEN 10 ELSE 0 END) `1st places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 2 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) `2nd places`,
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) `3rd places`,
format(avg(rating),0) `avg`

FROM contest_entries 
GROUP BY username 

) q, (SELECT @n := count(distinct username)+1 from contest_entries)
 n 
ORDER BY `points` asc) resultset where username = 'name1'
order by ranking asc;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3363f/44)

Comment: error in the code: "...right
syntax to use near '*) from contest_entries) n ORDER BY points asc' at line 11"

Comment: replaced distinct * with distinct username. Have a try now.

Comment: That doesnt really get what I want, but I have a feeling you're on the right track. When I want to select just one username "where username=name2" it brings back the rank of "2" for everyone.

Comment: that brings back a ranking of "0" for every user I try.

Comment: This is the first code your posted:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3363f/1

Then using the conditions this is the second:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3363f/2

See in the second link it says "where username=name1" it brings back a ranking of "2".

Comment: @Praveen - I've noticed you've been consistently answering [sql] queestions incorrectly.  I strongly suggest you take the time to *test* your answers before submitting them, and correcting those that have been downvoted; otherwise you run the risk of receiving further downvotes and being taken less seriously.

Comment: @MikeKochendorfer ::Updated answer with fiddle. Have a look.

Comment: @MikeKochendorfer Check now.